# Check if a class elements have same html content

Tags: jquery

I want to check if a class elements have the same html content.

Example;

```
<span class="test">100</span>
<span class="test">100</span>
<span class="test">98</span>
<span class="test">100</span>
<span class="test">100</span>
```

I want to find out if an element has different content, such as `98` number above

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the element with different content? Just show an alert or something?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What should happen when you have found duplicates?

Comment: @Zim84 i tried but couldnt do, thats why i asked it here

Comment: yes and WHAT have you tried?

Comment: @Zim84 tried sth with each function without any success

Comment: can you show us some code that you tried but did not work? SO is not for making answers from scratch, its helping you improve your solution.

Comment: @AdamPlocher yes just an alert and return false, thats all. someone did the answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way:-

```
$(".test").each(function() {
    if (Number($(this).text()) > 98)
        alert("Text contains > 98");
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/Yu26N/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try some code like this

```
$(".test").each(function(){
    var val = $(this).html();
    if(val!="100") alert(val);
});
```

[DEMO VIEW](http://jsfiddle.net/9Wj5e/)

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```
    var a = new Array();

    $('.test').each(function(index) {
        text = $(this).text();

        if ($.inArray(text, a) != -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            a.push(text);
        }

    });

    return false;
```